# IndexError: tuple index out of range & IndexError: dict index out of range

Tags: mysql

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect( user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='employees' )
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = " SELECT * FROM employer ; "
query ="SELECT  Name , Weight , Height  FROM employer ORDER BY Height DESC ,Weight "
cursor.execute(query)
dict = {}
for (Name ,Weight,Height ) in cursor :
     dict[Name] = Height,Weight
list = sorted(dict.items() ,key=lambda x:(x[1],x[2]),reverse= True )
for item in list :
     print(item[0],item[1][0],item[1][1])
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Please format your code. It is unreadable

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76969103/edit) button to make your code readable.